# How can I get Sublime Text to show package keybindings in the code window?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Please look at the example image below:

[image]

It looks like typing the package name is popping up a list of shortcuts.  Can anyone tell me how to set this up?  The image is from [sublime-jekyll](http://23maverick23.github.io/sublime-jekyll/) and I can’t seem to find an email for the developer or I would ask him directly. This would be very helpful for learning shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to be more specific on what exactly you are trying to set up, but hopefully this answers your question.

The key bindings shown in that screenshot can be accessed and modified at: **Preferences** -> **Package Settings** -> **Jekyll** -> **Key Bindings – User**

If you want to create your own key bindings, you can do so at: **Preferences** -> **Key Bindings - User**

The documentation for configuring Key Bindings can be found at: http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/sublime-text-2/reference/key_bindings.html

Comment: Thanks @Rocky.  I get a similar menu when I type a package name into the ST command line.  How can I set ST up so just typing a package name into the editor will pop open this list?

Comment: I think you are looking for the command Ctrl+Shift+P (on a mac: Command+Shift+P). That will show you the list of items in the screenshot plus others available. If you only want that list to show up when you type a word, you will have to write a custom snippet for that I believe. I haven't gotten too far into snippets yet.

Comment: Anton, no offense, but your reformat has made the instructions more difficult to read. You have added user steps to code blocks and replaced arrows with vertical bars. A vertical bar is not a good choice for showing progression as it typically implies OR logic. Furthermore, my final sentence is now grammatically incorrect thanks to your edits.

Comment: Re-edited Anton's edits. ^^